# Mapping to nested JSOn using pymongos Map Reduce

Tags: python, mongodb, mapreduce, pymongo

hi guys I'm getting an error with the code below:

```
collection = db.classifications

results = collection.find({"place":{"$ne":None}}, {"place.country_code":1})
for doc in results:
    print doc

map = Code("function(){emit(this.place.country_code, 1);}")

reduce = Code("function(key,values){return Array.sum(values)}")

result = collection.map_reduce(map, reduce, "results")

for doc in result.find():
    print doc
```

The error says it cannot read property 'country_code' on line 7.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself, so I'll post the answer for the curious...

I wasn't able to map to place.country_code because in some instances that property didn't exist e.g. place = Null.

So I instead added a query to only select the tweets where place was not null:

```
result = collection.map_reduce(map, reduce, "results",query={"place":{"$ne":None}})
```

Comment: Why do you need mapReduce for this- you can do this with simple aggregation